# What module for network card Intel Corporation Device 1521?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, networkcard

I'm installing a new server and I'm not able to figure out what module should I load to make its on-board network card work. Calling `lspci` prints:

```
Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 1521
```

I tried to google, but I couldn't find **what module should I load?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My server has the same Ethernet controller as yours, Intel Corporation Device 1521. According to `lsmod`, the module is `igb`.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be an Intel Ethernet Server Adapter I350 (T4 or T2). [This](http://www.intel.com/support/network/adapter/pro100/sb/CS-032498.htm) should help you install it.

Comment: That's not a module name.